# captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: completionHandler block not called on iOS 8 while focusing

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, avcapturesession

I'm using `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: completionHandler:`  to obtain image from capture session. Everything worked fine in my iOS 7 device, including iPhone 5c, iPhone 5, iPad2, iPad 4. However when I test my app in iOS 8 beta 5 device iPad mini 2, the situation are as following.

- If I capture photo when not focusing, everything was fine.
- When I tried to capture photo when focusing, whether its auto focusing or manually focusing, I just heard the shutter sound, but the completionHandler was not called.

What might the reason and how should I fix it?

Comment: I suggest you to file a radar.

Comment: @Thedude OK, When I upgrade to iOS 8 official version which was released yesterday, the problem seemed to be disappeared.